# Get object by LinqQuery

Tags: xml, linq

I have this XML-code and i want to filter out perssons that are in a specific institution.

```
</persons>
     <person>
    <name>
      <fn>Donald Duck</fn>
      <n>
        <family>Duck</family>
        <given>Donald</given>
      </n>
    </name>
    <email />
    <tel teltype="voice" />
    <tel teltype="mobile" />
    <adr>
    </adr>
    <institutionrole roletype="Employee" />
    <extension>
      <institutions>
        <institution institution="Division1">
        </institution>
    <institution institution="Division2">
        </institution>
      </institutions>
    </extension>
  </person>
</persons>
```

I want all the persons that are in the institution Division2.

With this code I get all the employees but not filtered on institution.

```
    var users = (from person in xmlDoc.Descendants("person")
where (person.Element("institutionrole").Attribute("roletype").Value.ToLower() == "employee"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like below to filter based on the nested elements; This will filter people with role type 'employee' and also if they belongs to given institution.

```
var users = from person in xmlDoc.Descendants("person")
                    where person.Element("institutionrole").Attribute("roletype").Value.ToLower() == "employee"
                    && person.Descendants("institutions").Elements("institution").Attributes("institution").Where(ins=>ins.Value.ToLower() == "division2").Any()
                    select person;
```